# How to Run blender from a python program?

Tags: python, external-applications

I was wondering how is it possible to have a blender program run exclusively from a python program? I am wanting to create an application that calls a python code to run blender. But is it even possible? If you know any tutorials on this, let me know.

Comment: Is this different from your other question? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58124/can-you-access-blender-from-a-third-party-application

Comment: well in my other question Im asking if i can use just eh addons, this one im asking if you can call a python script to run the blender, without having to use the interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run blender from python like this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["blender", "myScene.blend"])
```

Or, if you want, could run your python script from blender like this:

```
blender myscene.blend --background --python myscript.py
```

Comment: Okay, so where would i run the code

Comment: if you are running  your python script from blender, you would enter the code into the command line.  If you are running blender from python, just put the code in your python script.  If you have any problems or questions, just comment again.

Comment: so do you by chance know how to run a blender python script by command prompt

Comment: To run a python script from the command line, type `python absolutePathToScript.py`

Comment: how could i use addons through scripting mode

Comment: I think you would have to find out how the addon works, and import it into your script

Comment: I you have any more problems, let me know.  I'm moving this to chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42725/discussion-between-billy-s-and-alexander-pagan).